# How to remove title from each page?

Tags: titles

How to remove the title above each pages? The sentence "list of figures" appeared top of each page. How can I remove it?

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt, openany, titlepage]{book} 

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry} \newgeometry{tmargin=3.6cm, bmargin=3.6cm, lmargin=3.2cm, rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}

\begin{document}

\newpage 
 \setcounter{chapter}{1}
 \chapter[]{An influence oddddde on Fiber Bragg Gratddddor embed into adddtive manufdddd structure}

\textbf{TORddddd HFARD}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\newpage

 \section{Introduction} 
The material and methods utilized for investigate the effect of the temperature (both above and sub zero) on Fiber Bragg Grating (FBG) sensor embedded into additifffff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\mainmatter` directly after `\listoffigures` if you just want the title to be appropriate (for example "2.1 Introduction") rather than "List of Figures". If you want the title removed completely, can you please advise what you want in the header? Just the page number or? Can be done easily with `fancyhdr`

Comment: You should load `hyperref` as the last package too, it it risks being overwritten by other packages with strange or random errors potentially occurring as a result

Comment: `\pagestyle{plain}` will remove all headers and put the page number at the bottom of each page.  `\pagestyle{empty}` will remove the page number too (except for the first page of a chapter).

Comment: @ LaccaseTVersicolor
Thanks but this did not change my title correctly. list of figures shown in each page:(

Comment: It did on my system using your MWE, delete all your `.aux` and other files and rerun it maybe? If not, the header (and footer) can be customised if you let us know exactly what you want in it

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `book` class which means that document divisions should be specified in the order `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section` etc.

Change your `\section{Introduction}` to `\chapter{Introduction}`